# How to decrease usage of battery in android

Tags: android, battery, pjsip

I was developing a voip calling android application using pjsip sdk.
In my app am using PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCKS,ALARMS,SERVICES.

When making calls battery is decreasing more drastically.
What do I do to preserve battery life in this scenario?

Comment: My team has a VOIP app using PJSIP out in the Google Play market space and have noticed the same battery issues as well. VOIP calls in general are going to use significantly more system resources. The only things I can think of to look at are to ensure that you're using the appropriate type of wake locks and that you release them when you don't need them (these will kill your battery if you're not careful), and also to ensure that you're using the proximity sensor to turn the screen off while the user is in-call to decrease battery drain.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is too broad, it's complicated to help you.
You really should use Android Studio tools to see where your battery life is getting hurt.

I really really recommend checking this channel, with battery improvements patterns: [Link here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE)

The videos I recommend are:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81W61JA6YHw&index=24&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEEulSk1kNY&index=28&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D7_N2XEw20&index=57&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE

Comment: Before someone complains about posting linkings, FGS, it's YouTube and Google channel, if it goes down, it's the end of the world.

Comment: its also gone, when user gets closed or closes his account himself aswell

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I see why your battery is decreasing faster is that the SDK you are using is not optimized. I mean the code that is executed inside the SDK is the reason your battery is decreasing so fast.

- One solution would be to use another SDK,
- Another one is to create your application from scratch and be careful about optimizing your code so that the application won't eat all your battery.